# how to work with already created amplify backend with new react app?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-amplify

I want to add the backend files from amplify console(like amplify authentication, amplify api, amplify storage category) to my new react project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to add already creating amplify project (which is in console) in newly created react project to edit that backend from cli .Anyway sorry for my English. I am bad at explaning.

Answer (score 1):

In your react project, you need to take a pull from the amplify with your protect id.

```
amplify pull --appId [your-existing-amplify-backend-project-id] --envName dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to move my Amplify app from traditional Redux set up to Redux toolkit (RTK). Rather than moving new RTK set up to existing project, I figured it's easier to create a new RTK project and move the backend there. Below are the steps I followed:

- On the existing project, push all the pending changes to Amplify  - `amplify push -y`
- On the existing project, commit and push all the changes to git
- Initialise a CRA (with RTK in my case) - `npx create-react-app fifthcoffee-rtk --template redux-typescript`
- Pull Amplify dev environment - `amplify pull --appId <app id> --envName dev`
- Checkout `dev` environment - `amplify env checkout dev`
- Had to pull again on Amplify CLI's recomendation - `amplify env pull --envName dev`
- Check status. Everything should be up to day - `amplify status`
- Delete the `.git` hidden folder and copy the existing `.git` folder from previous project to this.
- Checkout a new branch for developmet - `git checkout -b feature/rtk-migration`